# How to scrape data from another website using Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I have a Rails 3.2.13 site that needs to scrape another website to get a product description. What is the best way to do this in Rails 3?

I've heard that nokogiri is fast. Should I use nokogiri? And if I use nokogiri is it possible that I don't have to save the scraped data anymore? I imagine it as just like getting json data from an API, is it like that?

Comment: What type of data do you need? One page or many? You'll have to save any data you want to be persistent; Nokogiri is only a parser and not a database. And, no, it's not like getting JSON data from an API. JSON is parsed into a Ruby hash or array. Nokogiri parses HTML and XML into a domain-object model which you have to navigate through and pull data from, based on XPath or CSS selectors you give it. Have you read Nokogiri's tutorials and *tried* using it to get an idea of what you're asking about?

Comment: I know a bit, I watched the Railscast but I just want to know if it's ok even if I will not save the data and just display it in my View once the page is requested. What I will scrape is just mostly string, a paragraph because it's a product description.

Comment: You don't have to cache/store the results of a page scrape. That's up to you. But, the delay of one scrape triggered by one hit by a user will be multiplied by all other users, slowing your app and their experience using your site. And it will waste your bandwidth to the site you are scraping, and their bandwidth returning a page you throw away. That adds up. So think about that consequence. I would cache the result and serve that for subsequent requests. You might need to periodically refresh the cache with updated data too, so plan for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend a combination of Nokogiri and open-uri. Require both gems, and then just do something along the lines of `doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(YOUR_URL))`. Then find the element you want to capture (using developer tools in chrome (or the equivalent) or something like [Selector Gadget](http://selectorgadget.com/). Then you can use `doc.at_css(SELECTOR)` for a single element, or `doc.search(SELECTOR)` for multiple selectors. Calling the text method the response should get you the product description you're looking for. No need to save anything to the database (unless you want to) Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

[mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) is a wonderful gem for scraping data from other websites **as html**. It is simple, robust and using nokogiri gem as result wrapper.

the following snippet will show you how you can fetch needed data being seen as Safari browser from url:

```
require 'htmlentities'
require "mechanize"
a = Mechanize.new { |agent|
    agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
}
@resultHash = {}

a.get(url) do |page|
    parsedPage = page.parser
    @resultHash[:some_data_name] = parsedPage.at_xpath("//h1[@class='any-class']").text.split(/\s+/).join(" ")
end
```